# What does the -t mean within iptables in linux?

Tags: owasp, ddos

I am setting up some iptables to help protect against DDos attacks for a university assignment. Im using the OWASP broken wep application and i have found some rules that work and ive figured out majority of the rules i just cant find out what the -t means. for example:

```
Iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntack –ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

This option specifies the packet matching table which the command should operate on. If the kernel is configured with automatic module loading, an attempt will be made to load the appropriate module for that table if it is not already there.
The tables are as follows:

**filter:**
This is the default table (if no -t option is passed). It contains the built-in chains INPUT (for packets destined to local sockets), FORWARD (for packets being routed through the box), and OUTPUT (for locally-generated packets).
nat:
This table is consulted when a packet that creates a new connection is encountered. It consists of four built-ins: PREROUTING (for altering packets as soon as they come in), INPUT (for altering packets destined for local sockets), OUTPUT (for altering locally-generated packets before routing), and POSTROUTING (for altering packets as they are about to go out). IPv6 NAT support is available since kernel 3.7.
**mangle:**
This table is used for specialized packet alteration. Until kernel 2.4.17 it had two built-in chains: PREROUTING (for altering incoming packets before routing) and OUTPUT (for altering locally-generated packets before routing). Since kernel 2.4.18, three other built-in chains are also supported: INPUT (for packets coming into the box itself), FORWARD (for altering packets being routed through the box), and POSTROUTING (for altering packets as they are about to go out).
**raw:**
This table is used mainly for configuring exemptions from connection tracking in combination with the NOTRACK target. It registers at the netfilter hooks with higher priority and is thus called before ip_conntrack, or any other IP tables. It provides the following built-in chains: PREROUTING (for packets arriving via any network interface) OUTPUT (for packets generated by local processes)
**security:**
This table is used for Mandatory Access Control (MAC) networking rules, such as those enabled by the SECMARK and CONNSECMARK targets. Mandatory Access Control is implemented by Linux Security Modules such as SELinux. The security table is called after the filter table, allowing any Discretionary Access Control (DAC) rules in the filter table to take effect before MAC rules. This table provides the following built-in chains: INPUT (for packets coming into the box itself), OUTPUT (for altering locally-generated packets before routing), and FORWARD (for altering packets being routed through the box).